# Install sqlsrv driver for laravel project with docker and php-alpine image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, sqlsrv

I need to connect on remote MSSQL database, I use docker enviroment. How to add sqlsrv driver, I have a docker file, as follows:

```
FROM php:8.0.5-fpm-alpine

ADD ./php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ Europe/Skopje

RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

This is what I find on an alpine-based Dockerfile to install it:

```
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
        wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
        apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
        apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
        apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS unixodbc-dev && \
        pecl install pdo_sqlsrv && \
        docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv && \
        apk del .phpize-deps && \
        rm msodbcsql17_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
        rm mssql-tools_17.5.1.1-1_amd64.apk
```

It doesn't works, but it compiled with no errors.
Can you provide mabye another dockerfile solutino.

I get error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Protocol
> error in TDS stream

Answer (score 1):

I ran over the same Problem and found this [GitHub-Thread](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/300#issuecomment-581573363)

So there is some [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#alpine-linux) about installing the driver on alpine linux.

Combining those two sources gets a current version of the driver. I included the following lines in my Dockerfile and they compile without problems:

```
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk && \
  wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/8/868e5fc4-7bfe-494d-8f9d-115cbcdb52ae/mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
  apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk && \
  apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk && \
  apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS unixodbc-dev && \
  pecl install pdo_sqlsrv && \
  docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv && \
  apk del .phpize-deps && \
  rm msodbcsql18_18.1.2.1-1_amd64.apk && \
  rm mssql-tools18_18.1.1.1-1_amd64.apk
```